# pip is throwing strange error when asked to list outdated packages?

Tags: python3, pip

I am currently using **Ubuntu 17.04** freshly installed just a few days ago. I installed **Python3.6** from the official repos and the package `python3-pip` to get **pip**. Today when I tried to list all the outdated Python packages in my system using `python3.6 -m pip list --outdated --format=columns` it gives me a strange error. Strangely this command works in my Manjaro installation running the same version of Python 3.6. How can I fix it?
[image: the error]

Comment: Is your pip up to date?

Comment: Upgrade your pip. If needed,  force-upgrade it.

Comment: pip is at **9.0.1**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also see this error when using `pip` inside a virtualenv for Python 3.6. One way to fix this is to force-reinstall `pip`:

```
python3.6 -m pip install -U --force-reinstall pip
```